# Segmentation fault from std::queue element deletion

Tags: c++, sockets, memory

I have the need to create a UDP buffer, I have chosen a `std::deque` to push and pop udp packets so that they can be stored. The deque takes the form:

```
std::deque<unsigned char *> packetStack;
```

Now each time a udp packet is called I do the following:

```
packetStack.push_back(new unsigned char[buffersize])
(nbytes = recvfrom(fdUdp, (void*)packetStack.back(), buffersize, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, &addrlen)) < 0)
if (nbytes <= 0)
{
     delete[] packetStack.back(); // Not sure if this one actually gets c
                                   // called but I dont think so. I assume 
                                   // it would fail in the same way as the one
                                   // below that i am about to explain.
     packetStack.pop_back();
}
```

Which i am pretty sure should work. I am providing the memory address of a buffer with `buffersize` reserved.

When i go to use these packets i do the following:

```
if (packetStack.empty() == false)
{
    function(packetStack.front());
    delete[] packetStack.front(); //segfaults here
    packetStack.pop_front();
}
```

So i get a segfault. I am not enjoying memory management in c++ so at this point i would like to ask **is there a better way to use socket calls than with `unsigned char *`?**

But I am not sure why this isn't working? I thought maybe it was the temporary assignment of the memory out of scope but then i tried this simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>


std::deque<unsigned char *> get(void)
{
    std::deque<unsigned char *> stuff;
    stuff.push_back(new unsigned char[20]);
    stuff.push_back(new unsigned char[20]);
    stuff.push_back(new unsigned char[20]);
    stuff.push_back(new unsigned char[20]);
    return stuff;
}

int main()
{
    std::deque<unsigned char *> stuff = get();
    delete[] stuff.back();
    stuff.pop_back();
    delete[] stuff.back();
    delete[] stuff.front();
}
```

And that all works just fine. **Unless i am missing something that will cause UB?**

The only other things that i can think of are that the `recvfrom` call is messing with the pointer address? Seems pretty unlikely.

Comment: I'm not offering an answer, just commentary. This is bad code. Instead of working with raw pointers like this, you should wrap each buffer in something: perhaps a unique_ptr, perhaps a custom object. Then the std::deque becomes a container of objects and their destructors do the cleanup for you.

Comment: @StevenSudit Yep, i am actually implementing that now cause i realized the same thing. I am still interested though in why this fails.

Comment: Like I said, I wasn't offering an answer. When something is this messy, it's easy to make some small, fatal mistake, and hard to figure out exactly what it is.

Comment: @StevenSudit I completely agree. Its an excellent suggestion. How will boost::unique_ptr work with that cast to (void*) in the `recvfrom` call do you think?

Comment: As far as I can see, **all** code you *have posted* is **perfectly fine**. Yes, it's better to wrap in unique pointers or [Boost.Pointer Container](http://www.boost.org/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html). But there is no reason this shouldn't work as written. I would take a guess that you somewhere (in the intervening code you didn't post) unintentionally copy the deque and consequently delete the same pointers multiple times.

Comment: @ben Regarding your question about the cast to void. In short, it won't. You'd be better off using something like `std::deque<std::vector<unsigned char>>` for your queue, reading your data into a local `std::vector<unsigned char>` sized appropriately, and `q.emplace_back(std::move(localvar))` to push your data on to your queue. I agree with Jan that the likely culprit is a copy of the deque, or a threading issue, but if it were the latter you would likely have mentioned it.

Comment: @WhozCraig the data comes from the `recvfrom` call, it requires a void pointer, if I give it `(void*)some_vector_with_space.data()` will that work?

Comment: The conversion from `unsigned char*` to `void*` is implicit, no need to cast, let alone a C-style cast which you should avoid. BTW: One big issue is that your container contains pointers, which means that copying it will give you two containers with identical pointer values! If one of them deletes an element, the according one in the other becomes unusable. My suggestion: Use a `struct udp_buffer{char buffer[SIZE];}` as element, this avoids the issues with low-level memory management and should work sufficiently.

Comment: @Ben I'd use std::unique_ptr if I was going to allocate directly. But WhozCraig is right: use a vector.

Comment: @WhozCraig Currently it looks like I have not provided enough information to answer the question as it is. Should I reword it so that it is more like, what is a better way to use socket calls in c++ and you can add your answer? This is the way i ended up doing it.

Comment: Is any part (either the writer or the reader) of your code residing in a DLL or passed as a callback to a DLL?

Comment: @atesgoral no one of it.